# Selecting every Nth element from a large MongoDB collection w/ PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with ~4M elements.

I want to grab X number of those elements, evenly spaced through the entire collection.

E.g., Get 1000 elements from the collection - one every 4000 rows.

Right now, I am getting the whole collection in a cursor and then only writing every Nth element. This gives me what I need but the original load of the huge collection takes a long time.

Is there an easy way to do this? Right now my guessed approach is to do a JS query on an incremented index property, with a modulus. A PHP implementation of this:

`db.collection.find({i:{$mod:[10000,0]}})`

But this seems like it will probably take just as much time for the query to run.

Jer

Answer (score 1):

Use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/).

This returns a random sample that is roughly "every Nth document".

To receive *exactly* every Nth document in a result set, you would have to provide a sort order and iterate the entire result set discarding all unwanted documents in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem, is that collection can be distributed over servers and thus you have to iterate over entire collection.

Comment: In this case I'm running the whole thing on a local server.

Answer (score 0):

Do not put the whole dataset in a cursor.  Since row order is not important, just collect x random rows out of your total, return that as a result and then modify those records

Comment: The problem is that I need evenly distributed elements from my collection - i.e. every 1000th element.

Comment: Create a count field, then use Map to filter each nth element, then Reduce to operate on that record

Comment: Thanks... will give this a try. I already have a count field in place. Just need to try to make heads/tails of the map reduce documentation.

Comment: Any progress?  Please vote my answer if it helped you and post your solution so other people can learn!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would design in a "modulus" value, populate it with something that is a function representative of the data - so if your data was inserted a regular intervals throughout the day you could do a modulus of the time, if there's nothing predictable then you could use a random value; with a collection of that size it would tend toward even distribution pretty quickly.

An example using a random value...

```
    // add the index
    db.example.ensureIndex({modulus: 1});
    // insert a load of data
    db.example.insert({ your: 'data', modulus: Math.round((Math.random() * 1000) % 1000) });
    // Get a 1/1000 of the set
    db.example.find({modulus: 1});
    // Get 1/3 of the set
    db.example.find({modulus: { $gt: 0, $lt: 333 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (inefficient) way to do this is with a stream.

```
var stream = collection.find({}).stream();
var counter = 0;

stream.on("data", function (document) {
  counter++;

  if (counter % 10000 == 0) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(document, null, 2));
    //do something every 10,000th time
  }
});
```

Answer (score -8):

If only your data was in a sql database, as it should be, ... this question wouldn't be in PHP and the answer would be so easy and quick ...

Loading anything into a cursor instead of calculating the information directly in the db is definitely a bad idea, is it not possible to do this directly in the MongoDB thingy ?

Comment: this answer is so backwards

Comment: When handling only 4M elements and doing operations that aren't native to MongoDB, you should be using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why? Why would PostgreSQL be better here? I am a heavy user of SQL databases but this kind of query is a bad one for most databases. Plus, "MongoDB thingy"? Doesn't seem like you truly know what your talking about with MongoDB to be authoritative here. Not even sure what you mean by the second part of your answer.

Comment: This query is perfectly fine in any good RDBMS (pgsql, oracle, mssql).